Node not found on calling function from preloaded script
So i'm calling a function from a preloaded script fire. But on running a program i'm getting this error:
FireActivate(): Node not found: "AnimatedSprite2D" (relative to "StaticBody2D").
I also tried preloading script under _ready() but i got the same error.
main.gd:
extends Node2D

var fire = preload("res://fire.gd").new()
func _ready():
    #if $Player.hit == true:
        #set_process_input(false)
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    Saw()
    for i in $Player.get_slide_collision_count():
        var collision = $Player.get_slide_collision(i)
        print("Collided with: ", collision.get_collider().name)
        
        box(collision)
        if collision.get_collider().name == "Trampoline":
            Trampoline()
        elif collision.get_collider().name.begins_with("Spikes"):
            Spikes()
            $MetalHitSound.play()
        elif collision.get_collider().name.begins_with("Saw"):
            $Player.die()
            $MetalHitSound.play()
        elif collision.get_collider().name.begins_with("Fire"):
            fire.FireActivate(collision)

func Trampoline():
    $Trampoline/AnimatedSprite2D.play("Jump")
    $Player.velocity.y = -1600
    $Trampoline/sound.play()
    
func Spikes():
    $Player.die()

func Saw():
    var speed = 5
    %PathFollow2D.set_progress(
        %PathFollow2D.get_progress()+speed)
    
func box(collision):
    if collision.get_collider().name.begins_with("Box"):
        $Box/AnimatedSprite2D.play("hit")
        $Player.velocity.y = -700
    else:
        $Box/AnimatedSprite2D.play("idle")

fire.gd:
extends StaticBody2D

var FireHit = false
    
func FireActivate(collision):
    if collision.get_collider().name.begins_with("Fire"):
        FireHit = true
        if FireHit:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("hit")
            $AnimatedSprite2D.play("on")
            $FireTimer.start(3)

func _on_timer_timeout():
    $AnimatedSprite2D.play("off")
    FireHit = false


Does the StaticBody2D to which the second script is attached have a child node named "AnimatedSprite2D"? It appears not.

I agree with @MaxAlexander try adding a screenshot of the scene to the question so it would help in identifying the issue better

Let us see what var fire = preload("res://fire.gd").new() does:
You have created a script fire.gd, and thus it is GDScript class. And since you have specified extends StaticBody2D, the fire.gd class extends StaticBody2D.
Now, the expression preload("res://fire.gd") will give you a GDScript object reprenting the fire.gd (The GDScript class is a meta class for the GDScript language).
And thus the expression: preload("res://fire.gd").new() will give you an instance of the fire.gd. Since this class extends StaticBody2D, in practice the expression gives you a StaticBody2D with the fire.gd script attached.
Finally the statement var fire = preload("res://fire.gd").new() declares a variable file of type Variant and initializes it with the newly created StaticBody2D that has the fire.gd script attached.

Now, let us see how you use the fire variable:
Evidently, you declare it and initialize it as explained above.
Aside from that, it is used in this statement: fire.FireActivate(collision). Here we are calling FireActivate instance method, passing the collision variable... Which is Variant initialized from get_slide_collision, so it is likely a KinematicCollision2D.

And finally we get to FireActivate, where the error happens: you are trying to access other nodes:
$AnimatedSprite2D.play("hit")
$AnimatedSprite2D.play("on")
$FireTimer.start(3)

In this case, we would be looking for two children Nodes with the names AnimatedSprite2D, FireTimer.
But remember you have a newly created StaticBody2D that has the fire.gd script attached - which was stored in the fire variable - and you never added children to it.
All you did was create it, and call a method on it. It has no children, and it is not in the scene tree. So it cannot access other nodes via get_node, the $ syntax or similar.

Without futher knowledge of how your scene is setup I cannot give you a full solution.
Now, perhaps this was a misunderstanding of what preload does, and you were expecting to get an already existing StaticBody2D... In which case, you should look into getting a reference to that node by other means (for example by giving it an unique name, or perhaps use node grups).
Or perhaps you didn't want to instante the fire.gd script, but a scene where the root note has the fire.gd script instead. In that scene it could have the AnimatedSprite2D and FireTimer children the script is looking for. However, you would still want to add it to the scene tree, and probably set its position.
However, it is possible that you intended the fire.gd class to be fully an utility class. In which case you could have the FireActivate method take references to the nodes it needs to work with (in this case it would not need to extend StaticBody2D)... And, of course, you could not use the fire.gd script and do all the logic in main.gd.
